# Get CountryData from 3 letter abbreviation of country name

Tags: string-manipulation, curated-data, interpreter

On browsing ATP rankings I stumbled on a simple problem

```
Union@Flatten[
 StringCases[
  Import["http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/rankings/singles", {"HTML", "ImageLinks"}]
  , {__ ~~ "/flags/" ~~ country__ ~~ ".svg" ~~ ___ -> country}
  ]
 ]
```

> ```
> {"arg", "aus", "aut", "bel", "bih", "bra", "bul", "can", "chn", \
> "col", "cro", "cyp", "cze", "dom", "esp", "fra", "gbr", "geo", "ger", \
> "isr", "ita", "jpn", "kor", "lux", "ned", "por", "rou", "rsa", "rus", \
> "srb", "sui", "svk", "tpe", "tun", "ukr", "uru", "usa", "uzb"}
> ```

**How do I get the [`CountryData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CountryData.html) from a 3 letter abbreviation?**

`CountryData["arg"]` and `CountryData["Arg"]` fails. `CountryData["Arg*"]` correctly gives `Entity["Country", "Argentina"]`, but that does not apply to the UK, for example, `CountryData["Gbr*"]`. `Interpreter["Country"]` doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Those look like IOC country codes, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IOC_country_codes, you can find a CSV file to import here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openmundi/world.csv/master/countries(204)_olympics.csv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
li = {"arg", "aus", "aut", "bel", "bih", "bra", "bul", "can", "chn", 
  "col", "cro", "cyp", "cze", "dom", "esp", "fra", "gbr", "geo", 
  "ger", "isr", "ita", "jpn", "kor", "lux", "ned", "por", "rou", 
  "rsa", "rus", "srb", "sui", "svk", "tpe", "tun", "ukr", "uru", 
  "usa", "uzb"};
```

Elements that don't match:

```
rep = 
  {"BUL" -> "BGR", "CRO" -> "HRV", "GER" -> "DEU", "NED" -> "NLD","POR" -> "PRT", 
   "RSA" -> "ZAF", "SUI" -> "CHE", "TPE" -> "TWN", "URU" -> "URY"};

li2 = ToUpperCase[li] /. rep;
```

Thanks to yohbs:

```
li2 /. Map[CountryData[#, "UNCode"] -> # &, CountryData[All]] // Multicolumn
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This creates a list of replacement `Rule`s to convert from 3-letter codes to the full name.

```
rules = Map[CountryData[#, "UNCode"] -> # &, CountryData[All]]
```

Comment: @kglr well, in that case the OP should describe the mapping from the abbreviation to the full name. Otherwise this would be a great solution: `country[abbr_]:=RandomChoice[CountryData[All]]`

Answer (score 4):

Just to document @JasonB's comment/answer in detail, the [International Olympic Committee (IOC) three-letter abbreviation country codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IOC_country_codes) replacement rule is available doing

```
Rule @@@ Rest@
  Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openmundi/world.csv/master/countries(204)_olympics.csv"
]
```

Still that fails somehow because `CountryData["Great Britain"]` is not recognised and needs to be changed to `CountryData["UnitedKingdom"]`.

---

Anyhow, even if not using [`CountryData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CountryData.html), now I can get the countries with most players in the ATP top 100 are:

```
With[
 {rule = Rule @@@ 
    Rest@Import[
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openmundi/world.csv/master/countries(204)_olympics.csv"]},
 Dataset@ReverseSort@Counts@StringReplace[
     Flatten[
      StringCases[
       Import[
        "http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/rankings/singles"
        , {"HTML", "ImageLinks"}
        ]
       , {__ ~~ "/flags/" ~~ country__ ~~ ".svg" ~~ ___ -> country}
       ]
      ], rule, IgnoreCase -> True
     ]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `Interpreter["Country"]` does a decent job on that list of countries, but fails on a couple like `"Congo DR"` and `"Virgin Islands (US)"`